# How to solve "Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1" in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

I want to require package from my local path (thiccpan/larashipcost), but i keep getting error like in the screenshot every time i do `composer-update`. How to solve this problem?. Thank you for your help.
Error image: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1iV9xJzNNlyVN7Y_lpU9XqoBV8u21IVo-?usp=share_link

I don't know what to do. I just want the package to be successfully required so I can test the package.

Comment: It seems you are using Windows OS and the system is trying to get path from the `/../...\..\...php`. I don't know, but this should might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/14743644/6196907

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information, please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557)